# GridPane in ScrollBar, stretch empty space

Tags: javafx, scrollbar, gridpane

I'am using javafx for building a GUI, including a GridPane with a MenuBar and another GridPane. I want that second GridPane to be scrollable, so I put it into a ScrollPane "new ScrollPane(grid2)", and added it to the first GridPane. Unfortunally, the content of the ScrollPane isn't streched horizontally anymore, if the window-size changes, what is needed.

Here is a pic, which should clearify the problem:
http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/scrollpaneemptwjpv2084xm.png
(cant use sof-tool, because reputation<10)

I want to have a big number of TitledPages, with a button in front of them, and which can be scrollable (unlike the menu, which should stay on top).

If i just add the second GridPane to the first one, it is streched in correct way, so I wonder why the ScrollPane or its element cant be streched also, and how.

I post you my code, thanks for reading this, and thanks for your effort!

```
package main;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text; 
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainGUI6 extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8824577253071530315L;
    JFXPanel panel;
    Scene scene;
    boolean wait = true;

    public MainGUI6() {
        panel = new JFXPanel();
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                GridPane grid = new GridPane();
                scene = new Scene(grid, 1000, 1000);
                grid.setVgap(4);
                grid.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

                //Menu
                final Menu menu1 = new Menu("Menu1");
                final Menu menu2 = new Menu("Menu2");
                final Menu menu3 = new Menu("Menu3");
                MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
                menuBar.getMenus().addAll(menu1, menu2, menu3);
                grid.add(menuBar, 0, 0);
                grid.setHgrow(menuBar, Priority.ALWAYS);

                //Second grid
                GridPane grid2 = new GridPane();

                //Buttons
                Button b1 = new Button("ButtonI1");
                Button b2 = new Button("ButtonI2");
                Button b3 = new Button("ButtonI3");
                grid2.add(b1, 0, 0);
                grid2.add(b2, 0, 1);
                grid2.add(b3, 0, 2);

                //TitledPanes
                TitledPane tp1 = new TitledPane("TitledPane1", new Button("Button1"));
                TitledPane tp2 = new TitledPane("TitledPane2", new Button("Button2"));
                TitledPane tp3 = new TitledPane("TitledPane3", new Button("Button3"));
                grid2.add(tp1, 1, 0);
                grid2.add(tp2, 1, 1);
                grid2.add(tp3, 1, 2);
                grid2.setHgrow(tp1, Priority.ALWAYS);
                grid2.setHgrow(tp2, Priority.ALWAYS);
                grid2.setHgrow(tp3, Priority.ALWAYS);

                ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane(grid2);
            grid.add(sp, 0, 1);
                grid.setHgrow(sp, Priority.ALWAYS);

                panel.setScene(scene);
                wait = false;
            }
        });
        this.getContentPane().add(panel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainGUI6();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ScrollPane` lacks the following:

```
sp.setFitToWidth(true);
```

To quote the corresponding API docs:

> If true and if the contained node is a Resizable, then the node will
>   be kept resized to match the width of the ScrollPane's viewport. If
>   the contained node is not a Resizable, this value is ignored.

Comment: Thougth i read every ScrollPane-method, but missed that one obviously. Thanks alot!